# Array multiplied by individual rows in matrix

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, multiplication

I have a 6,6,51 array and a 51,6 matrix. I want to multiply row 1 of matrix 1 in the array, by row 1 in the matrix and then store this as a result. I'd like to do this again for each row in each matrix contained in the array. So i'd take the second row of the 1st matrix in the array and multiply it by the first row of the matrix. Once I've cycled through all 6 rows of the first matrix in the array, I'd like to do the exact same thing on the remaining 50 matrices in the array.

To aid in the exposition of what I'm asking I'll give a shortened example using a 6,6,3  array and a 3,6 matrix.
I'll make up some numbers so it's easier to look at:

```
array1 <- array(1:108, c(6,6,3))

 [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    7   13   19   25   31
[2,]    2    8   14   20   26   32
[3,]    3    9   15   21   27   33
[4,]    4   10   16   22   28   34
[5,]    5   11   17   23   29   35
[6,]    6   12   18   24   30   36

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]   37   43   49   55   61   67
[2,]   38   44   50   56   62   68
[3,]   39   45   51   57   63   69
[4,]   40   46   52   58   64   70
[5,]   41   47   53   59   65   71
[6,]   42   48   54   60   66   72

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]   73   79   85   91   97  103
[2,]   74   80   86   92   98  104
[3,]   75   81   87   93   99  105
[4,]   76   82   88   94  100  106
[5,]   77   83   89   95  101  107
[6,]   78   84   90   96  102  108

matrix1 <- matrix(1:18, nrow = 3, ncol = 6)

   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    4    7   10   13   16
[2,]    2    5    8   11   14   17
[3,]    3    6    9   12   15   18
```

Essentially I'd like to do this:

row1 of matrix 1 in array1 x row1 of matrix1

```
1*1 + 7*4 + 13*7 + 19*10 +25*13 + 31*16 = result
```

then do row2 of matrix1 in array1 x row1 of matrix1

etc etc up until row 6 of matrix1 in array1

then repeat on matrix 2 of array1 using row2 of matrix1

Is this intelligible?

If so can someone help?

Alternatively, is there a way to split matrix1 into vectors? So I could just get 51 separate vectors to multiply against each array?

Regards

Comment: This looks like R. If so, tag it as such. If not, tag it with the appropriate language tag.

Comment: Are you sure about the size of the matrix? Shouldn't it be 6 x 6? Because if we have an array of dimensions 6 x 6 x 51, then there will be 51 matrices of 6 x 6. And If your question is correct, you are asking to multiply a 6 x 51 matrix with 6 x 6 matrix.

Comment: If the matrix dimension is 6 x 6 as Kunal Puri suggested, the solution would probably be: ``apply(array1, 3, function(x) rowSums(matrix1 * x))``

Comment: Imagine that I'm slicing the matrix (the 6,51 matrix), into  51 separate vectors, then multiplying each row of each matrix in the array by the i-th vector and doing this for all matrices in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as I'm still not sure if you mean 6 x 3 matrix or 6 x 6 matrix, here comes a solution for both cases (similar to my comment):

```
Rows <- min(dim(array1)[1], dim(matrix1)[1])
Cols <- min(dim(array1)[2], dim(matrix1)[2])

apply(array1, 3, function(x) rowSums(matrix1 * x[1:Rows,1:Cols]))
```

Further rows and columns of `array1` not fitting to `matrix1` are ignored then.

A short explanation how to get to the solution:
Take the first plane of the array and experiment to get the desired solution.

```
array1[ , , 1] * matrix1 #or array1[1:Rows, 1:Cols, 1] * matrix1
```

`rowSums` gives, as expected by it's name, the sum of each row. So the result for the first plane in the array multiplied with the matrix and summarised is a vector.

```
rowSums(array1[1:Rows, 1:Cols, 1] * matrix1)
# 1131 1284 1449
```

The result seems to be correct, now we can `apply` that solution on every matrix of the array as shown in the very top of the answer.